# msbuild does not compile all .cs files in project

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a .net solution which builds locally, but on our build server it fails to build, the errors are all something like:

> The type or namespace name 'XXX' does not exist in the namespace 'Foo.Bar' (are you missing an assembly referece?)

The strange thing that I've noticed is that when I inspect the DLL which is compiled locally with Just Decompile, the Type XXX exists in the Foo.Bar.DLL. When I inspect the Foo.Bar.DLL which is compiled on the build server the Type XXX does not exist, in fact non of the classes in the Foo.Bar namespace exist in the dll.

In my example, the namespace Foo.Bar contains classes which are all attributed with Serializable, XmlTypeAttribute and XmlRoot, could this affect the way that MSBuild builds the project?

Comment: That sounds a lot like XML serialization classes, the kind that are normally generated by sgen.exe.  Or the Project + Properties, Build tab, "Generate serialization assembly" option.  Or something to do with pr0n, obfuscating names doesn't help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the build generation order.(Right click on project, Project Dependency, Build generation Order)
It seem that the project with a reference with Foo.Bar.dll is compiled before the Foo.bar.dll
Add FooBar as denpendency of your project.
It compile in local because you have compiled manually FooBar before

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, but I also have to hold my hands up to making a mistake. It turned out that one of the projects was referenced as a compiled dll rather than a project reference. The compiled dll was being updated locally with each Visual Studio build but for some reason MSBuild was using an out dated version. I removed all references to the compiled dll and corrected them to project references and the issue is now fixed and I have a working build.